# Camera issue with CPU and software

Tags: camera, hardware

Because of my phone's CPU repair last time, my cameras had issues. When I factory reset, they get fixed for some time. But after some time, they give issues like the front camera is opening instead of the back, and the front wide angle is the normal camera, etc.

Tried clearing data and all the stuff that fixes normal camera issues

How do I fix it?

Comment: If the issue still persists after the factory reset, I think it's less likely a software issue but more probably a hardware issue. I recommend going back to that repair shop and asking for further checking and repairing of the camera. Without a specific model, we can't help much (though even with a specific model, AFAIK this community mostly focuses on knowledge of software, not tinkering directly with the hardware).

Comment: It's realme x3 I think it's a software issue maybe? Because everything works fine for few minutes to hours